# Linear or non-linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is this equation linear in $x$:

$$
x''+ v^2x' + x = \sin(v)?
$$

Here $x' = \frac{dx}{dv}$.

Comment: I know there exists an exception where the variable t can be combined with dependent variable and derivatives and the equation is still linear

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

This DE can be represented as

$$
\left(\frac{d^2}{d\nu^2}+\nu^2\frac{d}{d\nu}+1\right)x = \sin(\nu)
$$

or shortly

$$
\mathcal{D}[x] = f,\ \ \ \mathcal{D}[\cdot] = \left(\frac{d^2}{d\nu^2}+\nu^2\frac{d}{d\nu}+1\right)[\cdot]
$$

with $f$ independent of $x$.

The differential operator $\mathcal{D}[\cdot]$ is said linear over $\mathbb{R}$ if

$$
\mathcal{D}[\alpha x_1+\beta x_2] = \alpha\mathcal{D}[x_1] +\beta \mathcal{D}[x_2] 
$$

with $\alpha,\beta \in\mathbb{R}$

which is the case.

Answer (score 0):

In your notation, whenever $x, x', x'', x''',...$ appear as linearly, the ODE is linear. This means that their power has to be 1 and they cannot be the argument of any transcendental function such as $\sin, \exp, \log, \tan^{-1},...$

Answer (score 0):

The definitions I know of:

Linear differential equations are of the form $c_n(v)x^{(n)}+c_{n-1}(v)x^{(n-1)}+\cdots+c_1(v)x'+c_0(v)=f(v)$,

or: doesn't have products of the function x and its derivatives or powers [of the function x and its derivatives] higher than 1.

So it is linear.